# How to use conditional validation - 'greater than' and 'less than' with express-validators in express.js?

Tags: express, conditional-statements, express-validator

I am using `handlebar page` as template and `nodejs` for backend.

I want to use the `condtional validation if (a < b)` then show error msg on webpage.
But I am unable to do so with `express-validators`.

This is my below code I am trying its not working. I am using 2 letters keyword = `'lt'` indeed but its not working.

```
  router.post('/addtasks', function(req, res, next) {
  req.checkBody('topic', 'Empty Topic').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('website', 'Empty Website').notEmpty();

 req.checkBody('words', 'Empty Words').notEmpty().isLength({ min: 3 }).isInt({ lt: 2000});
});
```

The `first 2` are working throwing error msg on webpage. But the `3rd one` is not working.
Is there also `any other way`  or `express package` from which I can achieve this?
Thanks!

EDIT FOR WHAT I AM TRYING:

```
  router.post('/addtasks', function(req, res, next) {
      req.checkBody('topic', 'Empty Topic').notEmpty();
      req.checkBody('website', 'Empty Website').notEmpty();
var totalCount = 2000;
totalCount = totalCount - 500;
    
  req.checkBody('words', 'Empty Words or Min. Words = 500 Required or either Word limit exceeded').notEmpty().isInt({ gt:500, lt: totalCount});

    });
```

Here I want to put the `lt:` value dynamically which keeps changing every time not fixed. but here its not taking that. I need a  proper solution for this.

Comment: do you want to check less than 2000 condition only when the 'words' is an integer?

Comment: words data-type is an Integer. And i want to apply validation as it should not be greater than 2000 and less than 500.

Comment: In that case, BENARD Patrick's answer should solve your problem

Comment: Yes it is solving, but here the problem is that i have the min and max as variable means it keeps changing. ex -  var a = 2000; so i want to put the valuse as: .isInt({ min:100, max: a}); But this way its not taking the value.

Comment: I don't think having a dynamic variable is causing problem here. cause u share of more of your code snippet it might help solving the problem.

Comment: @malong11 I just added the codde what i am trying to achieve in the question. Check after EDIT please!!!

Answer (score 7):

`Express-validator` uses the `validator.js` library.

Following its [documentation](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators)

You should use `min` and `max` properties

```
req.checkBody('words', 'Empty Words').notEmpty().isInt({ min:100, max: 2000});
```

Extract :

> check if the string is an integer.
>
> options is an object which can contain the keys min and/or max to
> check the integer is within boundaries (e.g. { min: 10, max: 99 }).
> options can also contain the key allow_leading_zeroes, which when set
> to false will disallow integer values with leading zeroes (e.g. {
> allow_leading_zeroes: false }). Finally, options can contain the keys
> gt and/or lt which will enforce integers being greater than or less
> than, respectively, the value provided (e.g. {gt: 1, lt: 4} for a
> number between 1 and 4).